# Run only a part of a notebook

Tags: evaluation, notebooks

Is it possible to run only a part of a notebook?

I have a long notebook which takes forever to evaluate, so I was wondering if it was possible to run only a couple of cells instead of the whole notebook.

I know that I can run one cell at a time by using shift+enter, but I ask to run a couple of cells one right after the other 'automatically'.

Comment: Select the cells you want to evaluate and from the Evaluation menu, select `Evaluate Cells`. Shift-Enter works for the selected cells also.

Comment: @BillWatts thank you

Comment: Consider using section cells to make it easy to select all cells within a group.